# Realizar Toast desde una nueva clase Java en Android

Tags: android

Tengo una Activity principal llamada `LoginActivity`, la cual al hacer clic en un Button se conecta a una base de datos. He querido realizar la conexión en una nueva clase llamada `MiTurno`.

Mi problema radica en que me da un error al hacer un Toast (esto para mostrar errores como *CONTRASEÑA INCORRECTA*, etc) desde esta nueva clase y no sé cómo corregirlo.

Este es el código de LoginActivity.java (ver comentarios):

```
package com.windroid.dinas;

.....

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GlobalVariables globalVariables;

    EditText miUser;
    EditText miPass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        globalVariables = (GlobalVariables)getApplicationContext();

        miUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eUser);
        miPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ePass);
    }

    public void Login(View view) {
        new MiTurno().execute("http://10.0.3.2/baradm/sesion.php?id="+miUser.getText().toString());
    }
```

y este es la clase MiTurno que se realiza en una nueva clase llamada MiTurno.java:

```
package com.windroid.dinas;

......

    public class MiTurno extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    GlobalVariables globalVariables;

    public GlobalVariables getGlobalVariables() {
        return globalVariables;
    }

    @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            try {
                return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            try {
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);

               if (!ja.getString(1).equals(miUser.getText().toString())) {

//----> AQUI SE GENERA EL ERROR Y NO SE COMO SOLUCIONARLO

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "USUARIO NO EXISTE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Revisa los import a veces `Toast` da error en `AppCompatActivity` a causa de que falta algún import. ¿Puedes mostrar los import y parte del mensaje de error (sobre todo donde dice _Caused by_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega un constructor que reciba el contexto, para que pueda ser usado dentro del la clase `Asynctask`:

```
public class MiTurno extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private Context mContext;

    public MiTurno(Context context){
         mContext = context;
    }
    ...
    ...
```

Cuando llames el Asynctask inicializa con el contexto:

```
MiTurno miturno = new MiTurno(this);
miturno.execute("http://10.0.3.2/baradm/sesion.php?id="+miUser.getText().toString());
```

o simplemente:

```
new MiTurno(this).execute("http://10.0.3.2/baradm/sesion.php?id="+miUser.getText().toString());
```

esto es lo que se realiza generalmente para obtener el contexto en la clase que no puede acceder al contexto mediante `this`, `getActivity()` o `getApplicationContext()`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

puedes agregar una variable la cual sea una Activity y luego llamar a Toast pasandole esa actividad

Clase MiTurno

```
    public class MiTurno extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

GlobalVariables globalVariables;
Activity actividad;

public MiTurno(Activity actividad)
{
    this.actividad = actividad;
}

public GlobalVariables getGlobalVariables() {
    return globalVariables;
}

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);

           if (!ja.getString(1).equals(miUser.getText().toString())) {
    ----> AQUI SE GENERA EL ERROR Y NO SE COMO SOLUCIONARLO
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(actividad, "USUARIO NO EXISTE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Clase LoginActivity

```
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

GlobalVariables globalVariables;

EditText miUser;
EditText miPass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    globalVariables = (GlobalVariables)getApplicationContext();

    miUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eUser);
    miPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ePass);
}

public void Login(View view) {
    new MiTurno(this).execute("http://10.0.3.2/baradm/sesion.php?id="+miUser.getText().toString());
}
```